# How to search 471 strings in a table

Tags: postgresql

I want to make a `SELECT * FROM` of 471 strings in table rows, but is not working.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id 
                  FROM table2 
                  WHERE user_id = '(bla)|(bla2)|...|(blaN)') 
                    AND field3 IN (SELECT id 
                                   FROM table2 
                                   WHERE field4 = 'bleh');
```

I want to know if is correct search many strings in a same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN()`

```
WHERE user_id IN ('bla','bla2', 'blaN')
```

Comment: disclaimer,  that only works for searches with 471 strings.  ;-)

Comment: Maybe it would be better to insert the strings into a temp table and JOIN to it?

Comment: I want to list the users, then DELET them. Thank you!